# has_many :through with insert value on parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm having **has_many :through** association with User and City Model, In User new/edit form I'm able to add cities check boxes, but the same time I want use text filed for User input city if there is not existing cities as user wants.

In details if I have cities like **Indore, Bangalore, Pune** but user wants to insert new city in his account so through new text field User input their City, and if user input Mumbai and save then user must have Mumbai, as well as City model have now  **Indore, Bangalore, Pune, Mumbai** . Can any one help me how I can fields for this scenario.

Comment: EK bar `@user.cities.new` check kar ke dekh lo. Baki mujhe lagta h model me ek method bana lo wahi check kar lenge using `find_or_create_by` method something

Comment: Can give a try like , `accepts_nested_attributes_for :cities, :reject_if => :city_already_exists`

Comment: Not working only creating new record but not getting saved into user_cities table